# Error installing Fink on Mac Os X ("Argument 10.10 does not match the expected value of...")

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, fink

I'm trying to install fink on Mac, from source as there is no installer for 10.10. However I get this error when running the bootstrap command :

```
$ ./bootstrap 
Checking package...UNIVERSAL->import is deprecated and will be removed in a future perl at /Users/eino/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Checksum.pm line 27.
 looks good (fink-0.28.0).
Checking system... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
Use of uninitialized value $darwin_osx in numeric eq (==) at /Users/eino/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Services.pm line 1404.
Use of uninitialized value $darwin_osx in concatenation (.) or string at /Users/eino/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Services.pm line 1404.
Argument "10.10 does not match the expected value of . Please run ..." isn't numeric in exit at /Users/eino/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Services.pm line 1404.
DEGETEL-L0082-2:fink-0.28.0 eino$ ./bootstrap 
Checking package...UNIVERSAL->import is deprecated and will be removed in a future perl at /Users/eino/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Checksum.pm line 27.
 looks good (fink-0.28.0).
Checking system... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
Use of uninitialized value $darwin_osx in numeric eq (==) at /Users/eino/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Services.pm line 1404.
Use of uninitialized value $darwin_osx in concatenation (.) or string at /Users/eino/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Services.pm line 1404.
Argument "10.10 does not match the expected value of . Please run ..." isn't numeric in exit at /Users/eino/Downloads/fink-0.28.0/perlmod/Fink/Services.pm line 1404.
```

I'm running Yosemite 10.10.1, and trying to install fink 0.28 from [this link](http://www.finkproject.org/download/srcdist.php).
Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same issue, any solution ?